# How can i back up projects/code in Eclipse/Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, myeclipse

Ive been using eclipse and my-eclipse to code android and Java projects. I want to be able to back up my code. I know there is a way to back up code so that i can retrieve not only entire projects but changes and old versions but I cant figure out what the software is called and cant find any that are free and easy to implement. Any help would be great!

EDIT:
I don't have a server, can any of these be set up to save locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the plugins mentioned here will do, but I'm using the Subclipse plugin and a free repository at Assembla right now. I only switched from Mercurial because I started using Subversion at work.

If you don't have a server, you can try a free configuration at Assembla.com (http://www.assembla.com/catalog/tag/Free) for either Subversion or Git, and I've used Bitbucket.org in the past for hosting projects with Mercurial. Even the free configurations should be enough for your needs. I divided mine up between multiple projects.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll want to use version control software. There are great solutions out there - CVS, SVN, Git, Perforce. Most of them integrate nicely into Eclipse.

Developing software without VCS is unthinkable to me.

Comment: I dont have a server, is there a way for me to use any of these and save locally?

Comment: Absolutely. The server can be your own machine in all of the aforementioned solutions. Just be sure to back up the database to a separate drive or USB thumbdrive or whatever else. No point in backing up if you're doing it on the same device - if it fails, your data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

*Subversion* (at subversion.tigris.org) is one excellent package; there are many others. There are excellent Subversion plugins for Eclipse (google "Subclipse".)

Comment: Recent Eclipse versions come with SVN support more or less built in, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You may look to use the [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) package for Eclipse to use it with [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion). It permits you to keep/track/rollback changes and so.

The second option works fine if you need immediate result is to use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home#%3a%3a%3a). It is easy to configure and easy to share the folders among multiple computer.

Answer (score 0):

One more vote for using a VCS: in addition to back up you are getting control and some degree of methodology in your project.

Centralized solutions like CVS, SVN and Perforce mostly require setup and maintenance (some of them can run on flat files but these configurations are less popular). I would also consider one of the "Big Tree" distributed VCS [Git](http://git-scm.com/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) and [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en).

Mercurial seem to have strong [Eclipse plugin](http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE)